# Recursive Breadth Traversal Query (with max depth), Returning Nested JSON, Filtering the Initial Seed

Tags: postgresql, json, node.js, jsonb

> Since there wasn't much activity here, I've also asked [this question on regular StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76940588/4756173). If you happen to successfully answer here, do paste it there so you get more points.

In my DB, I have tables for `items` and `connections` between them, creating a likely sparse graph, with islands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    --------------------------------------------------------
    id    UUID         NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    --------------------------------------------------------
    title VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    --------------------------------------------------------
    CONSTRAINT     items_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    --------------------------------------------------------
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connections (
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    id                  UUID         NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    origin_item_id      UUID         NOT NULL,
    destination_item_id UUID         NOT NULL,
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    title               VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    CONSTRAINT     origin_item_fk
       FOREIGN KEY (origin_item_id)
        REFERENCES items (id),
    CONSTRAINT     destination_item_fk
       FOREIGN KEY (destination_item_id)
        REFERENCES items (id),
    CONSTRAINT     connections_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
);
```

I'm using `node-pg`, and I would like to do a breadth traversal from an inital seed (e.g. url parameter on ExpressJS), up to a certain depth (from what I see in the docs, the depth part is probably the easiest).

Ideally, I would like things to be returned in a nested way, but, from reading [these docs (`WITH` queries)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), I couldn't figure out how, or if it is even possible.

```
INSERT INTO items (title)
VALUES ('Software'), ('Pyongyang'), ('Burma'), ('Shenzhen'), ('Jerusalem'), ('Hostage');

INSERT INTO connections (origin_item_id, destination_item_id, title)
VALUES
    (
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Pyongyang'),
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Shenzhen'),
        'Same Author - Guy Delisle - 1'
    ),
    (
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Burma'),
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Pyongyang'),
        'Same Author - Guy Delisle - 2'
    ),
    (
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Jerusalem'),
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Shenzhen'),
        'Same Author - Guy Delisle - 3'
    ),
    (
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Hostage'),
        (SELECT id FROM items WHERE title ~ 'Jerusalem'),
        'Same Author - Guy Delisle - 4'
    ),
```

The recursive query would then result in, for `Pyongyang` and `maxDepth = 2` — note neither *Hostage* nor *Software* should appear then —:

```json
{
  "title": "Pyongyang",
  "connections": [
    {
      "title": "Same Author - Guy Delisle - 1",
      "destination_item": {
        "title": "Shenzhen",
        "connections": [
          {
            "title": "Same Author - Guy Delisle - 2",
            "origin_item": {
              "title": "Jerusalem"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Same Author - Guy Delisle - 2",
      "origin_item": {
        "title": "Burma"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> (I'm not 100% sure if I've covered all the cases with this example.)

Is this type of nesting even possible in PostgreSQL (with, say, `jsonb_build_object` or `jsonb_agg`)? How would I do it?

Here is what I've been able to do:

```
WITH RECURSIVE connections_and_items AS (
    SELECT
         c.id AS connection_id,
         c.title AS connection_title,
         c.origin_item_id,
         i.title AS origin_item_title,
         c.destination_item_id,
        it.title AS destination_item_title

    FROM connections c
    JOIN items       i
      ON  i.id = c.origin_item_id
    JOIN items       it
      ON it.id = c.destination_item_id
),
connected_items AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM connections_and_items
    WHERE origin_item_id = '${itemId}'::UUID

    UNION 
        
    SELECT c.*
    FROM connections_and_items c
    JOIN connected_items       ci
      ON ci.destination_item_id = c.origin_item_id
      OR ci.origin_item_id      = c.destination_item_id
) 

SELECT 
    ci.connection_id, 
    ci.connection_title,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id',    ci.origin_item_id,
        'title', ci.origin_item_title
    ) origin_item,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id',    ci.destination_item_id,
        'title', ci.destination_item_title
    ) destination_item

FROM connected_items ci
```

This actually does traverse the graph successfully, in both directions (!). However, I haven't been able to add a `maxDepth` constraint (having trouble detecting cycles), and the nesting is still not there.

So, in summary, here's what I have and what I'm missing:

- ✔ Recursive Breadth Traversal
- ✗ Max Depth
- ✗ Nested JSON
- ✔ Filtering the Initial Seed

---

### References

- [PostgreSQL Documentation - *`WITH` Queries (Common Table Expressions)*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)
- [PostgreSQL Tutorial - *Learn PostgreSQL Recursive Query By Example*](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/)
- [StackOverflow - *How does one print depth-level in a Postgres query that uses RECURSIVE to select descendants?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962204/4756173)